# Laravel: Call Custom Function from within another Model that hasMany()

Tags: laravel

I'm a laravel newbie and therefore I'd be interested in knowing if this is possible:

I have a model called Program and that hasMany('ProgramChangelog'). 
Now, it's known that it's possible to make something like this:

```
$program = Program::find(1);
$programChangelog = new ProgramChangelog(array());
$program->changelogs()->save($programChangelog);
```

But what if I'd like to do something like this:

```
$program = Program::find(1);
$program->changelogs()->createChangelog($change_occured);
```

The reason why I need this is because I'd like to define the text in the Model, depending on $change_occured and create the new entry based on this.

Of course I could do something like this:

```
$program = Program::find(1);
$programChangelog = new ProgramChangelog;
$programChangelog->createChangelog($program->id,$change_occured);
```

But I thought maybe it's possible and it would be good to know if or if not :)

Thanks!

Comment: hey, thanks! I wasn't sure where this suits best. Last time on overflow my question got downvoted and I was told that I should post here. Now I posted here (but this is another question) and it's the same thing again...

Comment: Why not just do `$program->createChangelog($change_occured);` and implement the `createChangelog` in your `Program` class?